# Why are notification action buttons laggy?

Tags: notifications, nexus-5x, 8.1-oreo, lagging

Let me explain my experience with the Android notification action buttons feature, where notifications from apps (often social media / communication apps) have buttons attached that can be used to like the message, retweet, reply, mark as read, etc.

Inconsistently, but frequently, when I press one of these action buttons, nothing happens for up to 10 seconds. If I don't wait for the notification to react to my pressing of the button, sometimes the button press never has ANY effect. And yet, sometimes the effect is instantaneous.

I have more success with some apps than with others. For instance, Android Messages is pretty responsive, Google Inbox is mediocre, and GroupMe is downright atrocious (I often have to wait more than 5 seconds after pressing "like" for the action to occur, and sending a reply with the action button almost never works).

Does anyone else have this experience? Is it just my phone? Or is it a matter of implementing this feature intelligently?

For context: I have a Nexus 5X running the latest Android 8.1.0.